# How to make setIn set a number key instead of array in immutable.js?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I have this code:

```
let toDayKey    = toDayKey.toString(); // 1
const deptId    = deptId.toString();  // 3
const jobId     = jobId.toString();  // 87

//Assuming copied.toJS() is any value like "copied job"

const calendar_job_add      = calendar_job_removed.setIn([toDayKey,deptId,jobId], copied_job.toJS());
```

calendar_job* is an immutable map, that Im trying to add a value to using `jobId` as key which is `87`

instead of getting  an object of

```
calendar_job_add = {"1": { "3": {"87": "the copied job" } } }
```

I get this instead:

```
calendar_job_add = {"1": { "3": {
0: undefined,
1: undefined,
2: undefined,
3: undefined
...
..
.
87: "copied job"
} } }
```

It seems to be turning it into an Array object instead of an Object and inserting undefined values. What gives?

Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what's going wrong from your code. When I call `setIn` on a `Map` and pass it numeric keys, it creates nested Maps all the way down, whether I use actual `number`s for those keys or strings like `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'`, etc.

```js
const before = Immutable.Map({})
console.log('before:', before);

const withStringKeys = before.setIn(['1', '2', '3'], 'a')
console.log('with string keys:', withStringKeys);

const withNumberKeys = before.setIn([1, 2, 3], 'b')
console.log('with number keys:', withStringKeys);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/4.0.0-rc.9/immutable.js"></script>
```

The only way I discovered to run into the problem you had was by trying to `setIn` something that was already a `List`. For example:

```js
const before = Immutable.fromJS({ 1: { 2: [] } });
console.log('before:', before);

const withStringKeys = before.setIn(['1', '2', '3'], 'a')
console.log('with string keys:', withStringKeys);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/4.0.0-rc.9/immutable.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have accepted your answer! ^_^ Your answer got me to the answer! Its because my object was initialize as [] = an array, immutable treat it as a list. I converted them all to object, and its working as intended. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I just made a work around as I couldnt find in the documentation/internet that would let me do what I want.

I just had to make the output object into javascript object with  `.toJS()` and use either the `object[jobId] = "copied job"` notation or `Object.assign({},{[jobId]: "copied job" })`

to add a value and put them back together again.